# Create opening application

Tags: java, android

I would like to display an image at the opening of my application Android (Java), is like a toast in full screen only.

That is, when you open the application and an image appears and disappears after you start the program.

What better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You mean Splash screen? If so, here is your answer: [Splash Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8983490/762919)

Answer (score 1):

It's called a SplashScreen
the links are here 
http://www.anddev.org/simple_splash_screen-t811.html 
and here 
http://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/01/01/android-splash-screens-done-right/

---

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Splash screen](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113831/An-Advanced-Splash-Screen-for-Android-App)  in android.
I found above link really helpful. There are lots of other article available. Just ask [Google](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=splash%20screen%20in%20nadroid&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an Activity with this image on the layout.

Then within this activity, create a Thread that will sleep for X seconds. When the Thread slept enough, start a new activity.

This is an example code :

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    public StartThread th;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        th = new StartThread(this);
        th.start(); 
    }
}

class StartThread extends Thread {
    SplashActivity parentActivity;
    public StartThread(SplashActivity splashActivity) {
        this.parentActivity = splashActivity;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();        
        try {
            this.sleep(3000);       
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            Intent menu = new Intent("com.yourpackage.yourapplication.NEXTACTIVITY");
            this.parentActivity.startActivity(menu);
            this.parentActivity.finish();
            this.parentActivity.th = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I use eclipse to develop for android, how to create another main activity beyond what is already the main, and how to call the two?

Comment: @GDawson right click on "src" -> "New" -> "Class" then work out